# Rails Engine isn't being loaded in asset precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, assets, rails-engines

I have a Rails Mountable Engine called Blog.

Inside the module, I have a method called root_path. The module loads the root path of the engine.

```
module Blog
  def self.root_path
    Engine.routes.url_helpers.root_path
  end
end
```

Inside one of the javascript assets of the Rails engine, I load the root url of the engine using erb syntax. Like the following line:

```
url = <%= Blog.root_path %>
```

When I run, `rake assets:precompile`, inside my app, I get an error saying the module does not contain such method. Like it isn't loading the engine library before precompiling the assets.

The error is:

```
undefined method `root_path' for #< Module:0xc185e14>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though Ryan's answer was helpfull, it wasn't the reason I was getting the error.

The reason was that I had set sep up initialize_on_precompile to false in my config/application.rb, so my app wasn't being started.

The Rails guides clearly states:

*For faster asset precompiles, you can partially load your application by setting config.assets.initialize_on_precompile to false in config/application.rb, though in that case templates cannot see application objects or methods*

Comment: Yeah, Rails Engines implementation kind of sucks. ;)

Comment: Also asset pipeline usually causes more trouble than it solves.

Answer (score 2):

Rails engines provide their routing helpers through a routing proxy. You don't need to define `root_path` methods like this.

Instead, call the method which is your engine's name and then the routing helper on it like this:

```
blog.root_path
```

For more information, read the [Engines Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html).

Comment: I get an undefined local variable or method name "blog" when I run rake assets:precompile. In the app, it works fine. But not when I run the rake task.

Comment: Yes, it will work fine inside the controllers/views for your application but you shouldn't be referencing it in assets. If you want to asset the engine path in assets [its a little more complicated](https://github.com/kunalchaudhari/spree/blob/266180a69daee79fe462bd8747b92066a34f0ec2/core/app/assets/javascripts/store/helpers.js.erb).